# Using htaccess to rewrite URL to aspx page gives 404

Tags: php, asp.net, .htaccess

I've just switched hosting provider (windows hosting) and sadly they don't offer IIS rewrites on shared hosting but they do allow htaccess, however when setting these up to rewrite to any .aspx page I get a 404 error. If I rewrite to any other type of file (htm, php, xml) it is fine, or if I do a 301 redirect it works fine, but I obviously want to hide the extension in the urls.

Going to https://www.rubysrambles.co.uk/test will show the sitemap but going to https://www.rubysrambles.co.uk/test2 will give a 404, but the redirect version will work fine. It's like it can't understand the aspx page? I've tried them both with and without slashes

My robots file looks like this:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/test$ /sitemap.xml [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/test2$ /dog-walking.aspx [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^/dog-walking$ https://www.rubysrambles.co.uk/dog-walking.aspx [NC,L]
```

Has anyone had any experience with this before, I understand it is odd as we'd normally use IIS but that isn't an option for me with this host.

Thanks

Comment: When configured in .htaccess, the path the rules are matching on _never_ starts with a slash, that has been stripped off at this point already. Neither of those rules _should_ be working in the first place. Remove the leading slashes, and try again. (And make sure to clear your browser cache, so as not to get fooled by cached redirects.)

Comment: Remove the leading slash from your rewrite pattern `^/test$` should be `^test$` if you are using rules in an htaccess file.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've just tried removing the slashes and still get the same issues. It is weird in that it works with any file except an aspx one, almost like it can't read it, but then it's fine when you go to the file directs.